# How to let users import from subfolders of my NPM package

Tags: typescript, npm, import, subdirectory

I want to let users import from the subfolders of my TypeScript NPM package. For example, if the directory structure of the TypeScript code is as follows,

```
- lib
- src
  - server
  - react
```

users of my package should be able to import from subfolders as `package-name/react`, `package-name/server` etc.

My tsconfig.json is as follows.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./lib",
      "strict": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
  }
```

I could do this when "outDir" was set to the project root, but then the file structure is messy. **Can someone point me a way out to do this (importing from submodules) while preserving `"outDir": "./lib"`?** Helpful answers are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share error you are getting while importing module.

Comment: when I try to import components as `import {component} from 'package-name/server'`, I get error `'package-name/server' is not found`, but when I import as `import {component} from 'package-name/lib/server`, I do not get such an error and everything work well. However, I want to get rid of that `/lib` part and users to directly import from `server` subfolder.

Answer (score 10):

That is possible with an entry in the package.json file called [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points):

```json
"exports": {
  "./server": "./lib/server",
  "./react": "./lib/react"
},
```

You can read more about it here: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points

But be careful:

> Warning: Introducing the "exports" field prevents consumers of a package from using any entry points that are not defined, including the package.json (e.g. require('your-package/package.json'). This will likely be a breaking change.

---

EDIT: It seems like TypeScript ignores the field, maybe it helps when you add types like this:

```
// server.d.ts
export * from "./lib/server";

// react.d.ts
export * from "./lib/react";
```

---

**What I did**

I copied your project setup and changed something:

```
src/
  server.ts
  react.ts
lib/
  (generated output)
  server.d.ts
  server.js
  react.d.ts
  react.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
react.d.ts
server.d.ts
```

Add this to package.json:

```json
"exports": {
  "./server": "./lib/server",
  "./react": "./lib/react"
},
```

*react.d.ts*

```
export * from "./lib/react";
```

*server.d.ts*

```
export * from "./lib/server";
```

That worked for me. Now I could import "mypackage/server" for example somewhere else. Maybe you didn't split up the definition files to multiple files, but try to apply these changes and see if it works.

Comment: Did you split it up to different files? It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add below `exports` entry in **package.json**

```
"exports": {
  "./": "./lib/"
},
```

After the entry you can import from within lib subfolder or file within lib folder but for subfolder within lib folder there need to be `index.js` file which would be imported.

Structure after typescript compilation that would work:

```
- lib
- src
  - server.js
  - react.js
```

```
- lib
- src
  - server
    - index.js
  - react
    - index.js
```

**Note:** `slash(/)` at the end of the entry are important for subpath export.

Example Steps:

```
mkdir -p mod1/src/api mod2/src
cd mod1
npm init -y
```

**mod1/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./lib",
      "strict": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

**mod1/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mod1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "exports": {
    "./": "./lib/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

**mod1/src/api/index.ts**

```
export const api = function() : void {
  console.log('api');
}
```

**mod1/src/react.ts**

```
export const react = function() : void {
  console.log('react');
}
```

**mod1/src/server.ts**

```
export const server = function() : void {
  console.log('server');
}
```

change to `mod2` directory

```
cd ../mod2
npm init -y
npm install ../mod1
```

**mod2/src/index.js**

```
const lib = require('mod1/server');
const { react } = require('mod1/react');
const { api } = require('mod1/api');
lib.server();
react();
api();
```

**Note:** I used `node` version 14.4.0 and `tsc` version 4.2.4

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your package.json file into your dist/lib folder as part of the publish process to avoid a messy repository structure.
[See here](https://github.com/hediet/ts-std/blob/9048668997704dd31d26b9f4dbd9dfaf5e8dc5f4/package.json#L6) for an example.
As a downside, yarn link might be more complicated and this approach might not work for yarn workspaces.

Alternatively, you can use the `exports` key in package.json once [TypeScript implements support for it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079).